# music can comfort yourself

Tags: grammaticality, reflexives

My girlfriend and I (both being not native speakers) are arguing little bit about grammar used in this sentence.

"music and painting can comfort yourself and it can reduce your stress"

She wonders about the usage of `yourself`. I think it's ok to use it that sentence.

Is it?

Comment: Why downvoted? Please explain ..

Comment: Your girlfriend is right. Your girlfriend is *always* right. Get used to it. The reflexive pronoun must refer to the subject (*music*)  in this sentence. Music is not comforting music; it's comforting you. You can say, "You can comfort yourself with music and painting, which can reduce your stress."

Comment: You have been struck by the driveby downvoter, a plague on this site. Likely your question is too elementary or didn't show enough attempts at "research". I am not the downvoter. In fact, here, let me help.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I would have no idea what to look for ...

Comment: Notice that ***It** can reduce your stress* has a singular subject (*it*), but the antecedent is plural (*music and painting*). Better ***they** can reduce* or the relative construction *which can reduce*.

Comment: I stupidly showed her your comment. She loved the `always` ...  anyway thank you for your time and explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Reflexives are used where the subject and object of the verb are the same:

> I comfort myself
>   You can comfort yourself

Here they are not. *Music and painting* are the subject of the verb, doing the comforting. So the object pronoun must be *you.* However, it is possible to introduce *you* as the subject, in which case a reflexive pronoun would be appropriate.

> Music and painting can comfort you and reduce your stress.
>   You can use music and painting to comfort yourself and reduce your stress.

(Note the omission of the superfluous *it can* in the first example; you don't need to repeat that.)

Sidenote: Reflexives can also be used for emphasis, but in that case they are always paired with the subject pronoun and are not used as object pronouns, as in "I myself use music."

Comment: Thanks. It's clear now. It was pointed out to me that I use yourself instead of you ....

Comment: How isn't this just an ELL question?

Comment: @Lambie I note you didn't do anything to migrate the question on that basis. Show me something that research could have found.